# Firmware-mod-kit failed with CRC update failed

Tags: firmware, crc

hello I'm trying to modify firmware to enable telnet support

when i tried to build firmware without any modification it give me these errors

```
    Firmware Mod Kit (build) 0.99, (c)2011-2013 Craig Heffner, Jeremy Collake

Building new squashfs file system... (this may take several minutes!)
Blocksize override (-min). Original used 1024KB blocks. New firmware uses 1MB blocks.
Squashfs block size is 1024 Kb
Parallel mksquashfs: Using 4 processors
Creating 4.0 filesystem on /media/isso/Storage/firmware-mod-kit/fmk/new-filesystem.squashfs, block size 1048576.
[=====================================================================================================================================================-] 1060/1060 100%
Exportable Squashfs 4.0 filesystem, xz compressed, data block size 1048576
    compressed data, compressed metadata, compressed fragments, compressed xattrs
    duplicates are removed
Filesystem size 5944.79 Kbytes (5.81 Mbytes)
    37.22% of uncompressed filesystem size (15971.71 Kbytes)
Inode table size 8598 bytes (8.40 Kbytes)
    21.21% of uncompressed inode table size (40546 bytes)
Directory table size 11036 bytes (10.78 Kbytes)
    43.50% of uncompressed directory table size (25373 bytes)
Number of duplicate files found 91
Number of inodes 1254
Number of files 1059
Number of fragments 14
Number of symbolic links  83
Number of device nodes 2
Number of fifo nodes 0
Number of socket nodes 0
Number of directories 110
Number of ids (unique uids + gids) 1
Number of uids 1
    root (0)
Number of gids 1
    root (0)
Remaining free bytes in firmware image: 1428295
Processing 1 header(s) from /media/isso/Storage/firmware-mod-kit/fmk/new-firmware.bin...
Processing header at offset 6288841...sorry, this file type is not supported.
checksum update(s) failed!
CRC update failed.

Firmware header not supported; firmware checksums may be incorrect. 
New firmware image has been saved to: /media/isso/Storage/firmware-mod-kit/fmk/new-firmware.bin
```

Comment: Open the original firmware in 010 (or similar) and open your modified version and then compare the headers to ensure the header is not corrupted.

Seems like your CRC calculation is incorrect: `Firmware header not supported; firmware checksums may be incorrect.`

Comment: Same problem here. Extracting a .trx and building the exact same files throws that error on ubuntu 22